# How to convert data signal line coding from RZ to NRZ?

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, digital-communications, telecommunications

I have a user data stream at 10 kbps and line coded as uni-polar, 0-5 Volts, RZ (return to zero).  What methods are there to convert this signal to an NRZ (non return to zero) format?

The only way I could think of so far was to run the user data through a "one-shot" circuit, and adjust the RC values to hold up for the other 1/2 the bit duration.  This approach seems flawed to me, and searching the internet did not yield any useful circuits.

Comment: a microcontroller may be the simplest solution

Comment: See "Easiest way to extend a pulse" https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/30691/239291

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reconstructing Clock for Serial Signal](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/107561/reconstructing-clock-for-serial-signal)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the responses.  I ended up using a D flip flop to convert from NRZ to RZ.  D input was the the user data, and using some logic chips to manipulate the CLK input, Q out signal was exactly what I needed.